# Angular Ui-Router with Jade Nested Views Broken

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Angular UI-Router works as expected as long as I do not use nested states. For example, this works:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/marketing");
$stateProvider
  .state('marketing', {
    url: '/marketing',
    templateUrl: 'partials/marketing',
  })
  .state('landing', {
    url: '/landing',
    templateUrl: 'partials/marketing-landing',
  })
  .state('features', {
    url: '/features',
    templateUrl: 'partials/marketing-features',
  })
```

And this doesn't:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/marketing");
$stateProvider
  .state('marketing', {
    url: '/marketing',
    templateUrl: 'partials/marketing',
  })
  .state('marketing.landing', {
    url: '/landing',
    templateUrl: 'partials/marketing-landing',
  })
  .state('marketing.features', {
    url: '/features',
    templateUrl: 'partials/marketing-features',
  })
```

In any case where a child URL (ie. /marketing/landing) is loaded either via a sref link or direct URL entry, only the parent partial (partials/marketing) is displayed, despite the address bar changing to the child's URL.

Index.jade:

```
div(ui-view)
```

marketing.jade:

```
h1 marketing layout

div(ui-view)
```

marketing-landing.jade:

```
h1 This is the landing page
```

marketing-features.jade:

```
h1 This is the features page
```

This is my first time using AngularUI. Let me know any other relevant information I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in Jade / bad assumption made by UI-Router (not sure which). From: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/247

> Use HTML in your jade file.  Jade won't expand it.

Answer (score 1):

First .ui-view - work correct!
But nested ui-view must be markup by plain HTML like this:

```
.row
  .col-md-12
    h4 Nested UI-VIEW
  <div ui-view></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an empty string to the ui-view attribute seems to work for me.  This keeps plain HTML out of the jade template and provides the ability to nest default jade content within the ui-view.

```
.row
  .col-md-12
    h4 Nested UI-VIEW
    div(ui-view='')
      p Using this approach we can have default content before ui-view is loaded
```